# Join two lines in one line (in Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of Lines and I am using it to draw vectors in my map.

I want to replace two superposed Lines (or have short distance between them) with one Line. Can you give an algorithm to do that ?

Here is a picture that helps you to understand this problem:

The Input Lines :

[image: The input Lines]

After executing the algorithm, I would like to to get the output represented in the following picture:

[image: Output]

PS: A Line is an ArrayList of points.

Comment: His question is asking for help on defining an algorithm that merges lines that coincide or are nearly coinciding.

Comment: If you look at most algorithms for finding the shortest distance between 2 lines, you'll find that it finds the points on each line that are the closest, then computes the distance from them

Comment: We can do something like create new arraylist and add all points if it doesn't already containing that point.

Comment: @user1843518, which algorithm you are using to generate line? Could you please post your code?

Comment: +1 nice question. sidenote: you will need more than joining - splitting too (if multiple lines form a T - like join, like in the bottom-right part of the image)

Comment: @AchintyaJha: I tried that. It doesn't work

Comment: @PradeepSimha: If i will post all the code. It will be hard to understand. I am using the google Direction API to get routes between multiple POI.

Answer (score 2):

1. Merge any pair of vertices that are within some fixed distance of each other (set their position to be equal).
2. Find the nearest point on each line to each vertex. If it's close enough, then split the line on that point, and merge the points.
3. Remove duplicate lines that have the exact same start and end points.

[image: Diagram]

For example, if you have a line defined by points A and B, and another line with point C (diagram on left above). The point D can be found using a shortest distance from point to line function. If D is too far away from C then ignore it, otherwise split the line AB into two lines AD and DB, and move all points in position C to position D, to get the diagram on the right.

Comment: I didn't understood the second step can you explain it more ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to the question "Do two ranges intersect, and if not then what is the distance between them?" The answer depends slightly on whether you already know which range is smallest already, and whether the points in the ranges are ordered correctly (that is, whether the lines have the same direction).

So a preliminary algo approach will be like this :

```
if (a.start < b.start) {
  first = a;
  second = b;
} else {
  first = b;
  second = a;
}
```

Let us find the distance now :

```
distance = max(0, second.start - first.end);
```

Now you have must have a range of values for shortest distance , depending on which you are going to super impose the lines into 1 . Lets say you have kept them  in an array called :

```
  arrayRange[];
```

Now if ,

```
for(int 1=0;i<arrayRange.length;i++)
{
if(distance is one of the elements of the arrayRange)
then,
callFunctionSuperImposeLines(distance,a,intersectionPoint,a.end,b,b.end);
}
```